# From PostgreSQL's Large Objects to Spring's ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, download

I'm trying to figure out how to upload and download to/from REST API implemented in Spring while the files are stored in PostgreSQL's Large Objects.

So far I've managed to upload a file and store it into the database. I've made sure of that using `psql` and `\lo_export` and I managed to save the file on hard disk. But the download part, I'm having trouble.

Here's a simplified version of the download code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/{file_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity download(@PathVariable Long file_id)
{
    Connection con = getConnection();
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    LargeObjectManager loManager = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)con).getLargeObjectAPI();
    LargeObject obj = loManager.open(file_id, LargeObjectManager.READ);
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(obj.getInputStream());
    con.commit();
    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"any.file\"")
        .contentLength(obj.size())
        .body(resource);
}
```

And when I call this API, I get the error:

```
java.io.IOException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid large-object descriptor: 0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like `file_id` is `0`.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the problem. I've made sure that if I enter some invalid `file_id` it will return "File not found" which it does. Also the file id is not zero.

Comment: Ah, your `con.commit()` probably prevents the blob from being read.

Comment: And what's the solution?

Comment: I don't know. Google gives plenty of results for "invalid large-object descriptor: 0" though.

Comment: Yeah it does but I didn't find any solution to my problem among them

Comment: You went through all of them?

Comment: Would you believe me if I tell you yes?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. This is *your* problem, and it's unlikely that anyone else will solve it for you. Google solves pretty much any programming problem there is, so it's up to you to choose how you proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance